# Azure PHP SDK: download container's all blob in a single zip file

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to download all blob from specified container as a zip file.
Is there any way to download its as zip directly from Azure, no need to process it on my server?

Currently I think like below:

`file_put_contents("file_name", get_file_contents($blob_url));`

I will store all files on my server and then create zip file of those and then will force to download.     .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure has no such facility to generate a zip file for a bundle of blobs for you. Azure Storage is just... storage. You'll need to download each of your blobs via php sdk (or directly via api if you so choose).

And if you want the content zip'd, you'll need to zip the content prior to storing in blob storage.

Your code (in your question) won't work as-is,  since `get_file_contents()` expects to work with file I/O, and that's not how to interact with blobs. Rather, you'd do something like this:

```
$getBlobResult = $blobClient->getBlob("<containername>", "<blobname>");
file_put_contents("<localfilename>", $getBlobResult->getContentStream());
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
By the way i was did it with my logic and working, code is as below
`$file_url = "https://mysite.blob.core.windows.net/container-name/" . $blob_name;
               
file_put_contents($local_server_file_path, file_get_contents($file_url));
                
$zip->addFile( $local_server_file_path, $prop_doc['image_name'] );`

Comment: How to fetch the blobs inside the folder in the containers? For ex: container_name/folder_name/blob

Comment: @Suraj - I would suggest asking a separate question, rather than here in comments. But... note that there are no "folders" when using Azure Storage blobs; it just looks like that due to the `/` character. So you'd have to enumerate based on a name pattern.